# MIME type text/html: how & where defined?

Tags: gnome, html, mime-types, xdg

I've asked a related question on AskUbuntu ([How to open *.htm differently than *.html?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162332/how-to-open-htm-differently-than-html)) with no interest yet, so I'm addressing the same issue with a more fundamental question.

I cannot find how and where in GNOME the MIME type `text/html` is assigned, usually (but not always) to web page files (`*.html` and `*.htm`).  There are at least 2 rules at work: it's partially related to the file extension as well as a variable number of characters at the beginning of the file (testing on GNOME 3.28.2 / Ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ ls -l empty.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 rphair rphair 0 2019-08-02 16:26 empty.html
$ gio info empty.html | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/plain

$ cat less-than.html
<
$ gio info less-than.html | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/html

$ mv less-than.html less-than.junk
$ gio info less-than.junk | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/plain

$ echo '<html' > less-than.junk
$ gio info less-than.junk | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: text/html
```

I need to know where this MIME type is defined as such, so I can change that definition.  (This goes a bit beyond the scope of this question, but my goal is to associate *.htm files of the same MIME classification with a web editor rather than a browser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing MIME types for installed packages are defined in `/usr/share/mime/packages`. Commonly accepted MIME types are defined in `freedesktop.org.xml` in this directory.  The content of this database is defined here ([freedesktop.org > Specifications > shared-mime-info-spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/)) as well as the procedure by which standard MIME types are added or modified.

Custom MIME types can be defined by placing files according to:

- [GNOME Help > Add a custom MIME type for individual users](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom-user.html.en): put in
  `/usr/share/mime/packages`
- [GNOME Help > Add a custom MIME type for
  all users](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom.html.en): put in `~/.local/share/mime/packages`

How to override standard MIME types (for the system in question, defined in package `shared-mime-info`), particularly `text/html`, is an answer to the related question, so I'll address it in the linked thread on the other forum.